# netty open 2 port server & 1 port client

Tags: java, netty

I want open 2 port on server, 1 for production, 2 for monitoring and 1 client for telnet to another server. but my server always got notifcation "to many open files" when run up to 1 day, my code like below :

```
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap( new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    private PipelineServer ps= new PipelineServer(listenMessage1);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(ps);

    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);

    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(server_port));

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap2 = new ServerBootstrap( new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    private PipelineServer ps2 new PipelineServer(listenMessage2);
    bootstrap2.setPipelineFactory(ps2);

    bootstrap2.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap2.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    bootstrap2.setOption("reuseAddress", true);

    bootstrap2.bind(new InetSocketAddress(server_port2));
```

listenMessage1 & listenMessage2 for communication betwen port production and port monitoring, handler decode and encode use StringDecoder() & StringEncoder(); but if the program run long time ex : 1 day, our log found "to many open files" and i can't connect to server.

Please your sollution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your ulimit setting ? It's quite to low by default for servers on linux. You can check with "ulimit -n". Set it to something bigger then 1024.

Comment: thanks for response, ulimit => unlimited, thats ok ?, my OS debian 7